# Limiting database hits

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app has users, plants and plantposts. Here are my associations

```
class User
  has_many: plants
  has_many :plantposts, through: :plantposts
end

class Plant
  has_many: plant_posts
  belongs_to : user
end
```

I have a list of active plants and I want to show the most recent( 3 max)plantposts for those plants without having to make a database call on every individual plant.

I thought it would a good idea to use one call to the `plantpost` table with the ids of all the active plants and put the results in a hash and then use the results to build my web page.

I'm not sure if this is the best way to approach this problem, or exactly how to construct the call to the plantpost table in the first place, or get the final results to show in the right locations in the second place.

Comment: You can store in Hashmap

Comment: SQL limit statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you made a mistake copying or if you have this wrong in your actual code, but your class/model definitions are a little strange to me.

Did you mean for them to be like this:

```
class User
  has_many: :plant_posts
  has_many: :plants
end

class PlantPosts
  belongs_to: :user
  belongs_to: :plant
end

class Plant
  has_many: :plant_posts
  belongs_to: :user
end
```

**Note:** I didn't write any `presence` validations as I'm still a little unsure what your rules are about that.

Essentially this is saying there are users who can have plants. Users can also make plant_posts for a certain plant, but that plant doesn't have to be theirs to do so.

---

Anyway, assuming you have an `active_plants` method that holds an array of `Plant`s:

```
# Query plant posts, ordered by mostly recently created, that are 
# for active_plants and return the top 3
PlantPost.order(created_at: :desc).joins(:plants)
    .where("plant_id = ?", [active_plants]).limit(3)
```

Comment: actually i have neither of those versions. My user class has_many plants and plantposts through plants. My Plant class has many plantposts and belongs_to just a single user. and my Plantpost class belongs_to both user and plant. I do not use a has_one association anywhere although it is true that a plantpost has just one user and plant, I wasn't sure if it was necessary to spell it out. Anyway everything works fine to this point. Thanks for this answer, I am going to try it out right now.

Comment: I'm just wondering if specifying the user for Plant **and** PlantPost isn't redundant, since this would technically allow for a PlantPost to reference a plant that belongs to a different user than it itself belongs to. Is that the way you want it?

Comment: No, not at all. I want a plantpost to belong to a single plant which in turn belongs to a single user. What is the best way to express that?

Comment: Ok I edited the original answer to incorporate what you've said. As I advised at the end, I would explore the possibility of eliminating the `PlantPost` class and putting everything in `Plant`. Again, this is assuming that there is a one-to-one mandatory relationship between the two, the code wouldn't be too incohesive in one class, and the class wouldn't be overly long.

Comment: I'm not sure if incorporating Plantpost into plant is what I want. Also, the relationship is plants have many plantposts not the other way around. In fact most of the data that ends up getting posted to this web site will be through multiple plantposts.  Again, Plantposts belong to plants. The other question is since plants belong to users should I even have to specifiy that plantposts also belong to users? I have done so in my models, but I'm not sure if it was necessary or helpful. However, since everything works at the moment as far as I can tell I'm not about to change it.

Comment: although come to think of it, it is very convenient being able to authenticate a Plantpost deletion when there is a user_id field in the Plantpost table.

Comment: I edited again to be what I believe you are describing.